# Foley project advice 

Tags: foley, recording, project, problems, solving

Hey guys I have a class foley project coming up soon and I would like to know how to recreate/record the sound of: 
sneakers "squeaking" on the floor and
glass breaking (like a window)

here are the restrictions:
It has to be done in front of the class and there is only a limited amount of time (15 minutes)to set up the mics (the amount and type available tba) AND record the take/s. The scene must be 30 seconds long (like a radio play)

We have some time to practise/rehearse and synchronize our movements up until the day of the project in front of the class. So I'd like my group to be really on point with setting up the mics quickly and knowing exactly what each person (including myself) must do foley-wise. Therefore allowing us more takes, but the trick is we will have to choose the best take.

[still need to find out]

The recording is either: 
Done by 1 person in our group (like controlling the faders/pan) 
or
We have to physically move the foley away from the mic (to fade the level) and/or move the foley from left to right passed one the stereo mics we will be using.
NB: we will not be mixing what we record, like in the industry, our recordings will be given to a another unknown person to mix.

I want the the sneaker foley to take place over different surfaces like concrete, up a ladder or maybe grass. 
Solutions:
I have a square concrete base umbrella stand roughly half a metre on each side will probably put a thick blanket underneath (prox effect) for the concrete surface.
I can get a big military desert storm camouflage thing for the grass.

As it is in front of the class we can't leave too much of a mess so the window/glass breaking will be a hectic challenge how would I solve this?

Comment: Thanks guys, it is confirmed that we can't touch the mixers so we will have to move the microphones/the folley sounds to emulate the pan and fades. The room is quite big it's a 200 seat auditorium but it has been treated for sound so reverb won't be that much of a problem.

Regarding the glass breaking we can't get a huge sheet of glass, so I was thinking of collecting empty wine bottles saw of the necks so the body is like a cylinder. So (obviously wearing gloves and eye protection) the two bottles will be smashed together, hopefully creating a nice sound.  

Comment: The brief is "running away from the cops" so I'm going for a thief breaking a window and stealing something, then hoofing it over different surfaces like: concrete and grass until finally the footsteps climb a ladder. We have +/- 12 people so one guys can do the footsteps other people can do them over the diff surfaces and one guy to do the breathing. What I really want to know is how to recreate the sound of climbing a metal ladder (like a fire escape)

Answer (score 1):

My two lira:

Sneakers: Sneaker squeaks can be loud and will have tons of room reverb if done indoors. Sneakers squeak the most reliably on very glossy varnished wood surfaces - in my experience, would love to hear others' - and you need a fair amount of speed to make 'em squeak on concrete. FWIW.

Glass: Eye goggles (actual safety goggles, not sunglasses), heavy leather gloves, and one or more very large canvas tarps or sound blankets, ideally arranged in a large "tub" (use gaffer's tape) supported by something like a circle of chairs. I prefer using a wrecking bar or long crowbar to a hammer; way safer, as it puts you much farther away from the shards. Never, ever put your hands or body parts under where the glass might fall. Wear long sleeves and pants. Don't forget a broom and a dustpan for cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of moisture will be essential for the shoe squeaks.